# Validar campos vacíos al cargar pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un sistema que al ingresar una placa y una cédula en los `input` me trae por medio de una consulta los datos de dos DB, pero quisiera que si alguno de estos campos no existe o esta en blanco se muestre una alerta y me retorne al formulario anterior, esto apenas cargue la pagina, es decir sin enviar formulario o ningún evento.

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    if('#PLACA'=="" && '#CEDULA'==""){
      alert("No se ha detectado el campo PLACA");
      document.write("Redireccionando...");
      setTimeout("window.history.go(-1)",1000);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row_consulta['PLACA']; ?>" name="PLACA" id="PLACA" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row_consulta['CEDULA']; ?>" name="CEDULA" id="CEDULA" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hace referencia al elemento y a su valor  con `val()` ,para poder comparar

> quisiera que si alguno de estos campos no existe o esta en blanco se
>   muestre una alerta

Es imposible que no existan dado que ya los está imprimiendo directamente desde el `HTML` , para validar si alguno de los dos entonces su operador debe ser un or `||`

```
if($('#PLACA').val() ==="" || $('#CEDULA').val() ===""){
  alert("No se ha detectado el campo PLACA Ni Cédula ");
  document.write("Redireccionando...");
  setTimeout("window.history.go(-1)",1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar la validación de los campos de la pagina cargada tendrías que tener un `script` que se auto-ejecute al cargar la pagina:

```
 $(function() {
         if($('#PLACA').val()=="" || $('#CEDULA').val()==""){
            alert("No se ha detectado el campo PLACA");
             document.write("Redireccionando...");
             setTimeout("window.history.go(-1)",1000);
          }
 });
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.